# Web application cannot find mysql driver

Tags: mysql, jetty, vaadin

The following code snippet fails already

```
    private void initConnectionPool() {
            try {

            connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root","mypassword", 2, 5);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

As background information. I am simply trying to connect to a database with Vaadin. The database exists and I already tested with a console java application that the driver is in the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. I could open an query the database.

On the web application with Vaadin, it tells me it can't load the driver. I already tried adding the .jar file to the build path. I dropped the .jar file as well in the target/hello-world/Web-inf/lib directory. I also added it to the Deployment assembly (project properties). I wanted to have maven handle that dependency but I don't know how to do it (I'm new to maven and I basically followed the Vaadin tutorial for running the web application on a jetty server).

So basically, I tried many things and my application cannot find the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver even if I put it in the web-inf folder. I've seen similar questions, and tried many of the potential answers but, so far, to no avail. Can someone please tell me what the easiest way of solving this could be?

For your info, I am launching the jetty server from eclipse as well.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: From your description it sounds like it's a maven project, so you shoud add the mysql driver dependency in your pom. If it's not, please add more details regarding your project setup and how you're running the app ide, stand alone server, etc

Comment: It's a maven project, but I'm new to maven and I don't know how to have it manage that dependency

Comment: Well, first you can read about [maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) and [its dependency system](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), then you can look for / google the [mysql library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.3) and add it to your [POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Introduction) file in the `dependencies` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try your proposed solution because I am using jetty. Anyway, just putting the file on the WEB-INF folder didn't do the trick either. In the end I managed to install the dependency via Maven and it works. I guess this is the case because I don't work at a large organisation with tons of firewalls.

I just right clicked on the project (Eclipse) and selected Maven->Add dependency

Group Id:mysql
Artifact Id:mysql-connector-java
Versions: 5.1.6

Then I went to the Run menu and selected Maven install.

This last version is a bit old and I am having other problem that might be related to it but, at least, not it opens the connection and it works.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Copy driver jar files to **WebContent > WEB-INF > lib**. 
If lib does not exist create it. Tomcat may find the driver from the specified folder.